# Como pegar os pontos de um círculo através de um ângulo em um plano cartesiano?

Tags: matemática, geometria

Imagine um circulo com raio de 5 no plano cartesiano.
Por analogia eu já sei os ângulos seguintes:

```
0° (ou 360°): (x =  5, y =  0)
90°         : (x =  0, y =  5)
180°        : (x = -5, y =  0)
270°        : (x =  0, y = -5)
```

Assumindo que o centro é x=0 e y=0, é claro.

Eu gostaria de uma equação onde é possível descobrir o x e y apenas através de um ângulo qualquer.

Comment: Problemas envolvendo matemática são interessantes, mas eles precisam estar envolvidos no escopo de alguma programação. No seu caso, me parece apenas uma questão de matemática comum.

Comment: É realmente uma questão matemática, mas será utilizada em um software com canvas 3D.

Comment: Então seria necessário mostrar na pergunta o código envolvido bem como a linguagem utilizada.

Comment: Minha pergunta é somente relacionada à matemática. Eu não consegui encontrar essa equação no google. Consegui apenas encontrar coisas relacionadas diretamente ao arco da circunferencia o que não é util para mim. Posso passar o link do projeto, mas minha dúvida é completamente matemática.

Comment: Eu recomendaria ajustar a pergunta para que ela tenha uma cara de programação e não de matemática. Assim vc tem chances de obter uma resposta. Da forma que está ela provavelmente será fechada por estar fora do escopo do site.

Comment: A comunidade de programadores já foi muito mais amigável. Eu postei essa pergunta, como você diz "com cara de programação" [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833044/given-an-angle-how-can-i-get-x-and-y-position) e fui reprovado como se eu tivesse feito uma pergunta absurda, agora estou novamente sendo sensurado.

É assim tão difícil informar uma fórmula matemática para alguém que não sabe? =(

(sad)

Comment: É que o site trata de assuntos relacionados a programação, e não de matemática. Talvez exista algum site da rede Stack que trate de matemática. Dá uma pesquisada.

Comment: Tem esse aqui olha: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isso de fato me ajuda! Vou postar essa mesma questão lá. Mesmo assim vou deixar esta aqui aberta, por enquanto. Quando tiver uma solução eu posto para responder aqui. Não é possível que eu seja o único que não sabe fazer isso. Obrigado, por enquanto.

Comment: Se conseguir lá posta aqui o link pra gente saber. Boa sorte!

Comment: O pessoal não fecha as coisas por maldade. Simplesmente cada rede da StackExchange tem escopos diferentes e por isso tratam problemas/perguntas diferentes. Logo tem de colocar a sua pergunta na rede certa sob pena de ser fechada abruptamente.

Comment: A pergunta da qual me referi esta no escopo certo. Em um escopo de programação com linguagem voltada a programação.

Comment: Diretamente da época dos computadores de 8-bit, considerando o centro do círculo como centro em (0,0), raio igual a 5 e ângulo em radianos -- X=0, Y=0, Raio=5 -- `X'=X+Raio×Seno(Angulo)` e `Y'=Y-Raio×Cosseno(Angulo)`

Comment: Só uma correção para ficar na sequência certa...é `X'=X+Raio×Cosseno(Angulo)` e `Y'=Y'+Raio*Seno(A)`

Comment: Obrigado Giovanni. Acredito que seja essa fórmula mesmo que estava procurando. Só mais uma coisa, no X' o apóstrofo significa algo matematicamente falando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar aprendi como isso deve ser feito e também que muitas pessoas também tem essa mesma dúvida. Acredite ou não, apesar de ser algo simples e pura matemática de ensino fundamental é um conteúdo pouco comentado na internet, pelo menos foi a impressão que eu tive. Talvez as pessoas imaginam que seja algo tão simples que pressupõem que todo mundo já sabe assim como ninguém imagina que alguém possa não saber multiplicar... Enfim...

De qualquer forma a resposta é tal como o Giovanni Nunes mencionou. Segue código:

https://jsfiddle.net/s67Lmx1a/39/

```
var x = Math.cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180) * raio;
var y = Math.sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180) * raio;
```

Ps.: Multiplica-se o angulo por PI e divide por 180 para se obter os radianos desse angulo. Essa era a parte que faltava para meu código funcionar.

Comment: Para aquele aventureiro que vier a ler esta resposta, tenha sempre no coração a seguinte frase: exceto se especificado o contrário, a biblioteca matemática que você está usando trabalhará com **radianos**, dificilmente trabalhará com graus.